# How to integrated multiselected field in dropdown list in Django

Tags: django, dropdown, multi-select

I want to implement a filter function for a multiselected field. Since there are a lot of options, I cannot list all the options plainly on the webpage.

I got the desire outcome from my colleague, which is integrating the multiselected in a dropdown list. As shown by the attachment. I wonder if it is possible to implement this using django? Has anyone do something like this?

Would like to hear any advice that helps. I would really appreciate your time and help!!

[Multiselected field in dropdown list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mj7yE.png)

Here is the model I need to use for this function. I use a django-multiSelectField package for Industry. What i am to do is, list all the options as a multiSelected field under a dropdown list.

[model.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOsv8.png)

Comment: We can't help until we know how does your models look like. And if possible do include the `forms.py` file also in your question.

Comment: @Ahtisham hi, thanks for your response. I attached the model on the post. In terms of the form.py, I don't have the idea to implement it yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can user  [MultipleChoiceField](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#multiplechoicefield) with the widget [CheckboxSelectMultiple](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple) in order to create something like this:

```
class CustomWidgetForm(forms.Form):

    SOME_CHOICES = (
        (1, "Havana"),
        (2, "New York"),
        (3, "Changai"),
        (4, "London"),
    )

    multiselect = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=SOME_CHOICES, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())
```

This will render the multiselect field like this:

[image]

And then you might apply a [custom template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/renderers/#overriding-built-in-widget-templates) to the `CheckboxSelectMultiple` widget in order to provide some js and render the widget just like you want.

Another approach is to use the default multiselect field combined with a Jquery plugin like [JQuery.sumoselect](http://hemantnegi.github.io/jquery.sumoselect/)

The mentioned plugin has the ability to make the selection box looks like:

[image]

There are many many possibilities but the sure thing is you'll have to involve JS into this.